# Unable to bulk insert using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, bulkinsert, stateless-session

I've tried adding bulk inserting to my application, but the Batcher is still NonBatchingBatcher with a BatchSize of 1.

This is using C#3, NH3RC1 and MySql 5.1

I've added this to my SessionFactory

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
```

And my code goes pretty much like this

```
var session = SessionManager.GetStatelessSession(type);
var tx = session.BeginTransaction();
session.Insert(instance);
```

I'm using HILO identity generation for the instances in question, but not for all instances on the database. The SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession doesn't take a type, so it can't really know it can do batching on this type, or...?

After some digging into NHibernate, I found something in SettingsFactory.CreateBatcherFactory that might give some additional info

```
// It defaults to the NonBatchingBatcher
System.Type tBatcher = typeof (NonBatchingBatcherFactory);

// Environment.BatchStrategy == "adonet.factory_class", but I haven't
// defined this in my config file
string batcherClass = PropertiesHelper.GetString(Environment.BatchStrategy, properties, null);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(batcherClass))
{
    if (batchSize > 0)
    {
        // MySqlDriver doesn't implement IEmbeddedBatcherFactoryProvider,
        // so it still uses NonBatchingFactory
        IEmbeddedBatcherFactoryProvider ebfp = connectionProvider.Driver as IEmbeddedBatcherFactoryProvider;
```

Could my configuration be wrong?

```
  <hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="my application name">
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">my connection string
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <!-- To avoid "The column 'Reserved Word' does not belong to the table : ReservedWords" -->
      <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, batching is currently supported for Oracle and SqlServer only.

As almost any other aspect of NH, this is extensible, so you can write your own `IBatcher`/`IBatcherFactory` and inject them via configuration.

Sidenote: current version of NH is 3.0 GA.

Comment: Sure? I seem to remember having used batching on MySql using Ado.Net before.. I cannot find much information on this either. Guess I'll have to dig into some code to see if I can get it at least partially supported. I know GA has been shipped. Just haven't gotten around to upgrading it.

Comment: There are only 3 implementations of IBatcher in the sources: OracleDateClient, SqlClient, and NonBatching, so I don't think that's possible. You might be confusing it with the `batch-size` property, which works with all DBs.

Comment: But batch-size doesn't have anything to say without an IBatcher, right?

Comment: It's completely unrelated, but I've seen people confuse them.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a year old, but there is [a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.MySQLBatcher) that adds MySQL batching functionality to NHibernate.  The reason that it's not baked directly into NHibernate is that the functionality required a reference to the MySQL.Data assembly, and the dev team didn't want the dependency.

Comment: Have you kept this package upto date with NH3.2+ 3.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Really old question but...let's be completely correct

Another reason for batching not working can be use of stateless session (as in your case). Stateless session does not support batching. From [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch):

> The insert(), update() and delete() operations defined by the
>   StatelessSession interface are considered to be direct database
>   row-level operations, which result in immediate execution of a SQL
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE respectively. Thus, they have very different
>   semantics to the Save(), SaveOrUpdate() and Delete() operations
>   defined by the ISession interface.